# Disable LFS locking API: What's the value of <unknown>?

Tags: git-lfs

Setup: I have my desktop computer added as a git remote on my laptop computer (`ssh://`), so that I can push from my laptop to my desktop:

```
> git push desk HEAD:refs/heads/featurebranch
```

This worked before – I have managed to disable the LFS check before, but this `<unknown>` error is new to me:

```
> git push desk HEAD:refs/heads/featurebranch
Remote "desk" does not support the LFS locking API. Consider disabling it with:
  $ git config lfs.<unknown>.locksverify false
batch request: missing protocol: "<unknown>"/s                                                                                                                                               
batch request: missing protocol: "<unknown>"
batch request: missing protocol: "<unknown>"
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://192.168.0.210:/home/me/git/repo'
```

Is `<unknown>` supposed to stand for something?

I suspect something is already off the rails here, because if I actually do what it suggests, by guessing the two obvious interpretations (taking it literally or as the remote name) …

```
> git config --global lfs."<unknown>".locksverify false
> git config --global lfs.desk.locksverify false
> git push desk HEAD:refs/heads/featurebranch
batch request: missing protocol: "<unknown>"B/s                                                                                                                                              
batch request: missing protocol: "<unknown>"
batch request: missing protocol: "<unknown>"
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://192.168.0.210:/home/me/git/repo'
```

… I can actually "solve" the first and userfriendly part of the error, but the remaining errors don't inspire confidence that it was supposed to work like this.

Answer (score 0):

1. The commits that change LFS files need to be synced out of band (because LFS [does not support ssh](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/1044)). For the simple case where the LFS changes come not from you, but from rebasing on origin/HEAD, do that on both sides:

   ```
   git fetch --prune origin
   ```
2. Same for the LFS files themselves. To pull these in, we need to check out a branch that contains those changes – most conveniently, by rebasing on said branch. On both sides:

   ```
   git rebase origin/HEAD
   ```
3. Even then, we can not push to a branch that is currently checked out (presumably because that would require updating the outchecked files, despite now being the same). The solution I have for now is to push a dummy branch first. Then, we can push to the current branch. And delete the dummy branch again. On the laptop:

   ```
   git push desk HEAD:refs/heads/dummybranch
   git push desk HEAD:refs/heads/"$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"
   git push desk :refs/heads/dummybranch
   ```